# Send payment to users using UPI APP in Android

Tags: android, upi

I'm working on a small project where I need to pay our users in small amounts. I want to find a simple UPI solution where we can do payment using UPI.

I'm working on UPI API **deep-link**, but it's only working on merchant UPI and not regular users. Let me know if you have a solution to the same problem.

Thanks.